# Questions time is link when loaded with websocket

Tags: bug, status-completed, google-chrome, web-sockets

The time on questions getting loaded with the *x questions with new activity* notification bar is shown as link.

New questions arrive:

[image: new]

Time is a link with text **modified x ago**:

[image: time as link]

But normal after refresh **asked x ago**:

[image: normal]

An example link of the time is [Cannot start mysql on xampp Version 1.8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782911/cannot-start-mysql-on-xampp-version-1-8-3%20class=)
 which has a redundant `%20class=` at the end.

Comment: What does it link *to*?

Comment: The question itself

Comment: I'd say the bug is shown in the lower half where the links are absent.

Comment: Link example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782911/cannot-start-mysql-on-xampp-version-1-8-3%20class=

Comment: @JanDvorak: No, that link should only be active in the "active questions" queue. Clicking on it there shows the last changed post in a question.

Comment: A redundant `%20class=`... Firebug shows a useless attribute `started-link"` with value `""`... Looks like someone's run two attributes together.

Comment: reproduced, looking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link should be there since it contains the `lastactivity` query parameter which does exactly what you would expect it to do...

The generation of the link tag was broken (href attribute was not being closed...) though, and will be fixed as soon as the next release rolls out (`2013.11.5.1596` meta, `2013.11.5.1119` sites).

Comment: But up to now the link **only** showed in the "active questions" queue. There it made sense to link to the last changed post. But on the "newest questions" queue - does it really make sense?

Comment: FWIW it won't be blue anymore but gray as all the other relative times... so could be you simply haven't noticed it earlier...

Comment: Currently it is no link when I refresh the page. Only a tooltip with the exact time.

Comment: Also the text is different before and after refresh: **modified x ago** and **asked x ago**

Comment: @m0sa I don't think live refresh should be used in the `newest` tab, only in the `active` per-tag tab. Having it used in the *newest* tab indeed cause weird mix of newest vs. active questions.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Nooooooooo!! This feature is awesome!

Comment: @juergend you started it! :D

Comment: @juergend I browsed through the code, and this (gray links with 'modified x ago') is the way it worked before the links were broken (yesterday)... everything else you've discovered now are just some good old skeletons in the closet :)

Comment: @m0sa: Since the behaviour has been changed, shouldn't the question be tagged [status-completed]?